# Mel parser outside of maya

Tags: macos, mel

Is there any way to execute Mel scripts outside of maya on osx? I'm trying to teach programming fundamentals so don't need to run maya commands, just a place to easily demonstrate variables, loops, functions, etc.

Thanks

Comment: From the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maya_Embedded_Language), it seems like MEL is similar to Perl and Tcl, but you can also use Python to script in Maya.

Comment: Yeah, MEL has similar syntax to a lot of other languages that are more universal, so I'm also thinking that it might be easier just to demonstrate basic concepts in something else. My goal isn't to actually write scripts though, but to teach very beginner MEL. I'd like to stay out of Maya while teaching the basics of variables and loops and such, and then jump into maya only when dealing with maya commands. So I'm looking standalone MEL interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of anything outside of Maya picking up and running with MEL however if just getting access to an interpreter without the clutter/distraction of the Maya GUI, you could run Maya in prompt mode (invoke maya with the `-prompt` flag)

(you could also open up a command port and do it that way.. but that might be more trouble than it's worth at that stage)

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I think it would be more trouble than it's worth in the end. I'm just running inside of maya.